# How can I handle an input prompt with node when executing a command via child_process?

Tags: node.js, typescript, 1password

For context, I'm on a Mac and I'm trying to script a 1Password CLI signin via their [command-line tool](https://support.1password.com/command-line/). I'm trying to programmatically sign in using a command that looks like:

```
op signin <signinaddress> <emailaddress> <secretkey> --output=raw
```

and I've tried with/without the `--output=raw` argument, but every time I simply get an error that looks like

```
[LOG] 2019/06/04 00:57:45 (ERROR) operation not supported on socket

child process exited with code 1
```

My initial hunch was that it had something to do with the command executions prompt displaying this special key character in the following image:

[image: op signin prompt img]

The relevant code is written in TypeScript and looks like this:

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process'

// ends up being `op signin <signinaddress> <emailaddress> <secretkey>`
const op = spawn(opExecutable, args);
let result: string | null = null

op.on('message', (message, sendHandle) => {
  console.log('message', message, sendHandle)
});
op.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
  if (data && typeof data.toString === 'function') {
    result = data.toString()
  }
});

op.on('close', (code, ...args) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`, args);
});
```

Eventually, I'd like to run on all platforms and be able pass in stdin for the master password required to sign in, but I'm trying to figure out why my node app is crashing first :)

Comment: I am trying to exactly the same thing and get exactly the same error. Any idea on how you solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was pretty close to a solution by using [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), but I needed to specify configuration for [`stdio`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio). Here's an example snippet of how I used `spawn` that worked for me:

```
const proc = spawn(
  cmd, // the command you want to run, in my case `op`
  args, // arguments you want to use with the above cmd `signin`, etc.
  {
    stdio: [
      'inherit', // stdin: changed from the default `pipe`
      'pipe', // stdout
      'inherit' // stderr: changed from the default `pipe`
    ]
  });
```